# Systemd-nspawn and gpgpu

Tags: systemd, gpu, opencl

I am trying to run a gpu-compute application inside of an nspawn container, i have configured the container as follows:

`/etc/systemd/nspawn/ubuntuintel.nspawn`:

```
argon# cat ubuntuintel.nspawn 
[Exec]
Capability=CAP_SYS_ADMIN

[Files]
Bind=/dev/dri
```

`/etc/systemd/system.control/systemd-nspawn@ubuntuintel.service.d/50-DeviceAllow.conf`:

```
# This is a drop-in unit file extension, created via "systemctl set-property"
# or an equivalent operation. Do not edit.
[Service]
DeviceAllow=
DeviceAllow=/dev/net/tun rwm
DeviceAllow=char-pts rw
DeviceAllow=/dev/loop-control rw
DeviceAllow=block-loop rw
DeviceAllow=block-blkext rw
DeviceAllow=/dev/mapper/control rw
DeviceAllow=block-device-mapper rw
DeviceAllow=/dev/dri rwm
```

Then i run the container via `systemctl start systemd-nspawn@ubuntuintel.service`

In the container the /dev/dri directory is present, but upon running the application this happens:

`openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/dri/renderD128", O_RDWR) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)`

What is the proper way to have the container use the gpu? I have also considered simply using qemu + pci passthrough but that is considerably heavier

Comment: You probably need to permit read/write access to the *device* `/dev/dri/renderD128` not just the directory `/dev/dri`.

Comment: Ah that did it, i expected it to act on the whole directory

Comment: you wanna make that an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: It was a guess! Someone who knows how it is *supposed* to work should probably give a proper answer.